# Button click event to open bookmarks on the internet

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an application that requires a user to be brought straight to their bookmarks screen on the internet upon a button click event. I have searched for examples but can't seem to find one. Is what I'm looking to accomplish possible.

My logcat on my onclick event

```
02-14 14:47:42.046 32686-32686/ideadline.ideadline E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3817)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3812)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=chrome://bookmarks/ }
      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1661)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3434)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3395)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3630)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3598)
      at ideadline.ideadline.StudyNotes.onClickbtnSavedArticles(StudyNotes.java:38)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3812) 
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about other browsers, but in Google Chrome you could use the URL that directly opens a bookmark directory in the browser: chrome://bookmarks/

[Chrome Bookmarks](http://chrome://bookmarks/)

As for other browsers, you'll just have to look up the alternatives and use to JavaScript to differentiate between which browser the user is using.

Hope this helps slightly:)

Comment: I'm trying this code and doesn't seem to be working I'm trying this code and doesn't seem to be working     `public void onClickbtnSavedArticles(View view) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("chrome://bookmarks/#1"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }`

Comment: I added my logcat I just think it can't find that url